# conditional field in anonymous records, in f#

Tags: f#

I often use anonmymous records to build on the go data that will eventually be serialized and returned to be consumed somewhere else. This is very flexible, quick to deal with, etc.

But one thing I'm really missing is the ability to do something like this pseudo code:

```
{|
    SomeData = 3
    StartTime = ....
    if ProcessedFinished then yield { EndTime = ... }
|}
```

when I could add a field, or not, based on some conditions.

Is there a solution to have the flexibility of the anonymous record, yet have the ability to make conditions like this? I could do a dictionary, then insert values based on conditions but then I'd have to box all the values as well and it would be messy right away.

Comment: Here's a question to ask yourself: what would be the type of that expression? And what should happen if you pass such record to some other piece of code, which then tries to access the `EndTime` field?

Comment: This is output that gets serialized as a part of an api (within internal services) where the consumer is in JS and everything is pretty much treated as a dictionary there. So this works well since they’re used to see if something exists, or not, as a crude replacement for option types

Comment: So just use `Option` then

Comment: I was thinking that it would serialize as null (the data represent financial data updates, so only fields with updates are present), but yes, I can ask the serializer to ignore the null values. Simple, but it didn't cross my mind! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you're after is not possible today, but you can get pretty close like so:

```
let initialData =
    {|
        SomeData = 3
        StartTime = ....
    |}

if ProcessedFinished then
    {| initialData with EndTime = ... |}
else
    initialData
```

Of course, to represent this as a return type it's now more involved, as you'll likely need to use SRTP in the signature to account for any type with a `SomeData` and `StartTime` member on it. It's perfectly fine if this is just in the body of a routine that then produces another result to return, though.

If you want to represent data that may be optionally available based on a condition, especially if you want it to live outside of a given function, I'd recommend an option for that field instead.

Comment: Using `with` is a neat trick! But you'll need to add something to make the `if` type-check. If this is just JSON serialization, I guess `box` would do.